# I want to know the code that targets the person who gave the command

Tags: discord.js

I want to know the code that targets the person who gave the command instead 'message.mentions.members.first();'

I want to create a way to change my nickname by typing a command, but I always have to do an mention

The code consists of this configuration.

> module.exports = {
> name: "nick",
> async execute(message, args, client) { const member = message.mentions.members.first();
>
> if (!member) return message.reply("Please specify a member!");
>
> const arguments = args.shift(2)
>
> if (!arguments) return message.reply("Please specify a nickname!");
>
> try {
> const arguments = args.shift(2)   member.setNickname(arguments); }catch (error) {         console.error(error);
>
> } }, }

Comment: if you are following anything like the suggested construct here: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#individual-command-files ... then the CLIENT entity is the one that called the command ;-) ;-) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If `message` is the message sent by the user invoking the bot command, you can access the user that sent that message using the [`.author` property](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=author) on the Message.

Comment: message.members.author is not function...  could could you tell me in detail

Comment: `message.author` as stated in the answer. You can also do `message.member.user`

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to get member of the guild (server) use `message.member` or if you want the user then `message.author` or `message.member.user`. To change the nickname you would want to use `message.member.setNickname(arguments)`

Comment: I follow your advice, but I get an error   "DiscordAPIError[50013]: Missing Permissions"

Comment: Your bot does not have permissions to change nicknames in the server.

Comment: my bot has administor permission....

Comment: Ohh i see, the bot's rank/role is below your rank/role so it cant change the nickname

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem has been solved. We have confirmed that it was not a problem with the rights of the bot, but a problem with the rights of the user. And I confirmed that the bot was at the bottom of the Admin.

Comment: Close the post then